# General exponential function $z^s$ in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

In most of the books on complex analysis, the function $z\mapsto z^s$ for suitable $s$ is defined with the complex logarithm and exponential function:
$$z^s=e^{s\log z}.$$
(Some books do not describe this function, beyond $s\in \{n,1/n\}$ for $n$ a natural number.)

**Question:** Can one suggest some book in which, the exponent $z^s$ is defined without logarithm and exponential?

Comment: You can also just use the [complex argument $\arg\left( \cdot \right)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html) and the [CiS function $\operatorname{cis}\left( \cdot \right)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cis.html): $$z^{s} = \left| z \right|^{s} \cdot \operatorname{cis}\left( \arg\left( z \right) \cdot s \right) = \left| z \right|^{s} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \cdot s \right) + i \cdot \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \cdot s \right) \right)$$